# Is there a vertical scroll event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a function that I bound with `scroll()` event, but the fact is I want the function to be triggered only in case of vertical scroll ( I have some horizontal scroll too).

I didn't see such possibility in the documentation of jQuery, might there be a trick to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a specific event, but you could test the `.scrollLeft()` position to see if it has moved from a previously stored position.

Something like this:

```
var prevLeft = 0;
$(document).scroll( function(evt) {
    var currentLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if(prevLeft != currentLeft) {
        prevLeft = currentLeft;
        console.log("I scrolled horizontally.");
    }
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Comment: I don't know why I didn't even think of that. Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for. (I just used scrollTop() instead because it fitted my situation)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use  `.scrollTop` to make a custom vertical scroll event.

```
var prevTop = 0;
$(document).scroll( function(evt) {
    var currentTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(prevTop !== currentTop) {
        prevTop = currentTop;
        console.log("I scrolled vertically.");
    }
});
```

[Jquery .scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var prevLeft = 0;
$(document).scroll( function(evt) {
    var currentLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if(prevLeft === currentLeft) {
        console.log("I scrolled vertically.");
    } 
    else {
        prevLeft = currentLeft;
    }
});
```