# How to get the number of pixels a user has scrolled down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

Suppose we have a html page with large height.So there will be a vertical scrollbar.

As the user scrolls down I want to know how much he has scrolled using javascript (jquery) I suppose... Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this using [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     // use the value from $(window).scrollTop(); 
 });
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186622/is-there-a-vertical-scroll-event-in-jquery).

Answer (score 65):

In pure javascript you can simply do like that:

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    console.log(window.scrollY); // Value of scroll Y in px
};
```

More infos (The Mozilla Developer Network) :

- [onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)
- [scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

Comment: I am surprised that no one upvoted this. +1 from me ;)

Comment: Do you need to unregister this somehow before exit as you do with `removeEventListener`?

Comment: Wow!!! Mate you saved me in 2020!!! Thanks a lot!!!! You are a star!!

Answer (score 6):

This is what i used on my website... when anyone scrolls 620 pixels down the menu will pop up, I input the numbers manually. I'm still a noob at javascript but I hope this helps

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scrollTop = 620;
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop){
                $('.Nav').css({
                    position : 'fixed',
                    top : '0'
                });
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop){
                $('.Nav').removeAttr('style');  
            }
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: While this works, it could be improved, no need for the second if statement, just use an else. Also just removing the 'style' attribute could be dangerous if there is something else inline styled, perhaps by another js function. I think a better practice would be to reverse the style you added in the initial if

Answer (score 5):

Yes. See [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) in jQuery, which wraps the [scrollTop](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php) DOM property.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **window.scrollX** to detect how much pixels the user has scrolled right.
You can use **window.scrollY** to detect how much pixels the user has scrolled down.
You can use **window.scrollTo(x, y);** to set scroll pixels right (x) and down (y).

---

Example code:

```
var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
window.scrollTo(0, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine in chrome

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log(scrollY);
});
```