# jQuery scrolling left and right event handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Is there an event handler in jQuery that watches for scrolling left and right?

I wanted to do something like

```
$('document').ScrolledLeft(function() {
    console.log('user scrolled left!');
})

$('document').ScrolledRight(function() {
    console.log('user scrolled right!');
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look for jQuery scroll event and `$(document).scrollLeft();`

Comment: The other question was just catching horizontal event and was not specifying wether it's a left or right scroll event. I modified it to catch left and right scroll.

http://jsbin.com/duxirada/1

Answer (score 0):

From another question

[Is there a vertical scroll event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186622/is-there-a-vertical-scroll-event-in-jquery)

```
var prevLeft = 0;
$(document).scroll( function(evt) {
    var currentLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if(prevLeft != currentLeft) {
        prevLeft = currentLeft;
        console.log("I scrolled vertically.");
    }
});
```