# How to detect changes on horizontal or vertical scroll?

Tags: angular

I have vertical and horizontal scroll. I want to check if user use horizontal scroll to do something or if user vertical to do something.

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) onElementScroll($event) {
    let horizontal = $event.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
    let vertical = $event.currentTarget.scrollTop;
    this.h == horizontal ?  this.sticky = true : this.h = horizontal;
    this.v == vertical ?  this.sticky = false : this.v = vertical;
}
```

This is my code, but i dont know how to know when user use vertical or horizntal scroll. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the `event.scrollTop` and `event.scrollLeft` from the previous event and compare them at the next event to derive if the user scrolled vertically, horizontally, or both.

See also [Is there a vertical scroll event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186622/is-there-a-vertical-scroll-event-in-jquery)